# Xamarin Forms ScreenShot Handler

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

hola amigos necesito cachar el evento de `ScreenShot` en Xamarin Android hasta ahora encontre como evitar que se haga el ScreenShot, pero necesito cachar el evento para almacenar los intentos del mismo en algun lado. Hasta ahora encontre esto para deshabilitarlo

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // justo esta linea es la que me permite quitar el screenshot.
        this.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure, WindowManagerFlags.Secure);

        Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);            
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());

    }
```

alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Un bonito by-pass para características así: usar otro teléfono para tomar foto.

Comment: @fredyfx yo solo sigo ordenes padre, por más sin sentido que sientas mis preguntas

Comment: Me gustaría saber más sobre Xamarin para darte una mejor guía, sabes que todavía soy un noob mobile dev y ahí le vamos :D Si encuentro alguna manera, te colaboro con esa feature. Saludos hermano

Comment: Hola @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim, podrías chequear el siguiente enlace, en el cual según entiendo trata sobre lo que necesitás, mas que nada donde mencionan el flag FLAG_SECURE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764568/prevent-screen-capture-in-android-apps

Comment: Encontre unas soluciones para checkar eso tipo de eventos, pero casi todos tienen comentarios que no funcionan bien o no en todos los modelos. [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532502/detect-a-screenshot-android/40218889#40218889) se han finalmente hecho la cosa de diferente media: para observar eventos de contento cambiados en la memoria y de tipo de un ScreenShot. Solo, no se si esta ya tarde, porque el contenido ya esta escrita.